# Regex to place substrings in proper groups

Tags: regex, string

I have some strings that consist of street address, city and zip. It is not guaranteed that all components are present. Street address, if present is the first item. City and zip have a label before them. Examples:

```
01_foo_street City: bar_city ZIP: baz
City: bar_city ZIP: baz
01_foo_street ZIP: baz
ZIP: baz
01_foo_street City: bar_city
City: bar_city
01_foo_street
```

Note that the 8th item is a blank string.

I need a regex that returns exactly three groups: street address, city and zip. If a component is missing the group should be empty. I tried the following, which matches, but does not generate the expected result:

```
^(.*)(?: City: *(.*))?(?: ZIP: *(.*))?$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex with optional groups:

```sh
^([^:]*?)(?: *\bCity: ([^:]*))?(?: *\bZIP: (.*))?$
```

Or this one with few more steps in regex engine:

```
^(.*?)(?: *\bCity: (.*?))?(?: *\bZIP: (.*))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vONgMr/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `([^:]*?)`: First group for street address that matches 0 or more of any characters that are not `:`
- `(?: *\bCity: ([^:]*))?`: Second group for city name that matches 0 or more of any characters that are not `:` inside an optional non-capture group that starts with `City:`
- `(?: *\bZIP: (.*))?`: Third group for zip name that matches 0 or more of any characters inside an optional non-capture group that starts with `ZIP:`
- `$`: End

---

If you want **empty groups** in the result for the absent data then consider this PCRE regex:

```sh
^([^:\s]*?\b)(?| *\bCity: ([^\s:]*)|())(?| *\bZIP: (.*)|())$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/vONgMr/3)

Comment: There are no new lines in string. In my example one line is one input.

Comment: Yes I totally understand that. On regex101 demo I had to use `\n` because there are multiple inputs per line.

Comment: I think this is it reading the question again :-)

Comment: thanks @Thefourthbird I have added a PCRE variant for empty groups also

Comment: Ah, I was trying to find a way how to do that..cool with the branch reset group.

Comment: What is the significance of using `[^:]*?` instead of `.*?`?

Comment: That is mostly used for performance reasons. `·*?` pattern will do much more backtracking in regex engine than the `[^:]*?`